# How to retrieve intermediary state in TensorFlow RNN

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am running an RNN on a signal in fixed-size segments. The following code allows me to preserve the final state of the previous batch to initialize the initial state of the next batch.

```
rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=init_state)
```

This works when the batches are non-overlapping. For example, my first batch processes samples 0:124 and `final_state` is the state after this processing. Then, the next batch processes samples 124:256, setting `init_state` to `final_state`.

My question is how to retrieve an intermediary state when the batches are overlapping. First, I process samples 0:124, then 10:134, 20:144, so the hop size is 10. I would like to retrieve not the `final_state` but the state after processing 10 samples.

Is it possible in TF to keep the intermediary state? The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/static_rnn) shows that the return value consists only of the final state.

The image shows the issue I am facing due to state discontinuity. In my program, the RNN segment length is 215 and the hop length is 20.

[image: Sample results]

Update: the easiest turned out to be what [David Parks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49890068/4008884) described:

```
rnn_outputs_one, mid_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, rnn_inputs_one, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
rnn_outputs_two, final_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, rnn_inputs_two, initial_state=mid_state)
rnn_outputs = rnn_outputs_one + rnn_outputs_two
```

and

```
prev_state = sess.run(mid_state)
```

Now, after just a few iterations, the results look much better. [image]

Comment: In the image, the orange line is the target value and the blue line is the RNN result (every sample maps to one sample).

Comment: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/ It's not really an answer since it's  different API (which is also working with tensorflow) but are you looking for a parameter like return sequence which returned all outputs of the rnn as sequence instead of only the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tensorflow the only thing that is kept after returning from a call to `sess.run` are variables. You should create a variable for the state, then use `tf.assign` to assign the result from your RNN cell to that variable. You can then use that Variable in the same way as any other tensor.

If you need to initialize the variable to something other than `0` you can call `sess.run` once with a placeholder and `tf.assign` specifically to setup the variable.

---

Added detail:

If you need an intermediate state, let's say you ran for timesteps 0:124 and you want step 10, you should split that up into 2 RNN cells, one that processes the first 10 timesteps and the second that continues processing the next 114 timesteps. This shouldn't affect training and back propagation as long as you use the same cell (LSTM or other cell) in both `static_rnn` functions. The cell is where your weights are defined, and that has to remain constant. Your gradient will flow backwards through the second cell and then finally the first appropriately.

Comment: Thank you! I clarified the question. The tensorflow structure is working correctly but I am not sure how to retrieve specific information from a high-level TF API.

Answer (score 0):

So, I came here looking for an answer earlier, but I ended up creating one.

Similar to above posters about making it assignable...

When you build your graph, make a list of sequence placeholders like..

```
my_states = [None] * int(sequence_length + 1)

my_states[0] = cell.zero_state()

for step in steps:
    cell_out, my_states[step+1] = cell( )
```

Then outside of your graph after the sess.run() you say

```
new_states = my_states[1:]

model.my_states = new_states
```

This situation is for stepping 1 timestep at a time, but it could easily be made for steps of 10. Just slice the list of states after sess.run() and make those the initial states.

Good luck!

Comment: This approach seems conveniently generalizable! Would you mind explaining in more detail the line `cell_out, my_states[step+1] = cell( )`?

Comment: Sure!

If you unfold an RNN instead of calling tf.rnn(cell, inputs, etc.)

You loop over the cell N times. 

It's basically pulling the inside of the tf.rnn(cell, inputs, etc.) to the outside and making your graph contain a for loop. 

If you look at truncated BPTT articles, this is a fairly common architecture approach, as it gives more control over the network.